# Как вернуть одно значение и выйти из рекурсии

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, рекурсия

Я должен переписать код рекурсивно, но рекурсия у меня на уровне easy-задач на литкоде.
Есть код:

```
def main():
    for i in range(1, n):
        recursion(i)

def recursion(i):
    for ...:
        if ...:
            return False
        elif ...:
            recursion(i)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы этот `return False` остановил цикл `for` в функции `main()`, то есть в целом прекратил выполняться (и рекурсия прекратилась), а если этого `return False` не произошло за весь цикл, то после завершения цикла сделать `return True`

Я пробовал писать `print("NO"); return`, но он мне 3 "NO" печатает и понятно почему, с флагами пытался делать, но безуспешно, 100% есть проще

UPD Циклом это должно выглядеть так:

```
def main():
    recursion()

def recursion():
    for i in range(1, n):
        value[i] = ...
        if ...:
            return False
        elif:
           ...
    return True
```

Comment: А зачем в принципе помещать рекурсию в цикл? Пока что это похоже на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Comment: @nomnoms12 а как иначе передавать в рекурсию каждый раз новое значение

Comment: Вы можете передавать в рекурсию каждый раз новое значение. Собственно, это делается для того, чтобы достичь крайнего случая и выйти из рекурсии. Можете привести изначальную задачу?

Comment: @nomnoms12 задача состоит в том, что мне нужно перебрать все вершины в цикле. то есть каждый раз передавать в рекурсию start_vertex, с которой функция будет идти до конца структуры. поэтому я передаю каждый раз в цикле в рекурсию новое значение, а как иначе можно сделать, нельзя же в самой функции такое проворачивать - она просто не работает, что и логично, собственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полной уверености нет, но для раннего прерывания рекурсии и цикла нужно возвращать из `recursion` флажок "продолжай", который проверяет вызывающая сторона:

```
def main():
    for i in range(1, n):
        if not recursion(i):
            break

def recursion(i):
    for ...:
        if ...:
            return False
        elif ...:
            if not recursion(i):
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все верно понял:

1. Вы неверно преобразовали цикл в рекурсию
2. Думаю так ваша проблема решиться

```
def main():
    if recursion(1):
        print('Not False')
    else:
        print('False')

def recursion(i):
    for ...:
        if ...:
            return False
        elif ...:
            return recursion(i+1) # <---
        return True
```

Comment: Цикл стал бесполезен - всегда делает только одну итерацию. Вы видимо хотели его совсем убрать?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy именно, а иначе не вижу смысла переделевать в рекурсию. но ответ построен на догадках, поэтому довольно смутный